# How SQL join work?

Tags: sql, join

i am using MYSQL..
I have two tables:

```
TABLE 1 (TABLE NAME T1)
SL   NAME
1     a
2     b
3     c
4     c 

table 2 (table name T2)
SL   NAME
1     a
2     c
3     c
4     c
```

Q1: how i count the total number of 'c' in both table?

Q2: which name is max occurrences in both table?

sl is primary key...
my query is:>
select count(*) from t1,t2
where t1.name=t2.name where t1.name='c';
but it showing 6

Comment: Even if you may find help for your homework here, you should at least show what you tried...

Comment: Q3: What have you tried? Don't expect us to give you the answer without you doing any effort.

Comment: Whats the difference between T1 and T2? -> Normalization

Comment: Also, you should tag the question with what RDBMS you're using (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle etc.)

Comment: use join, where condition and count to get your answer

Comment: @PandiyanCool JOIN - on which primary/foreign key?

Comment: can't you just count in each and add the number ?

Comment: You really shouldn't lean on Stack Overflow for help with your homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count `c` in both tables you should use `UNION`, not `JOIN`.

Syntax:

```
SELECT ...
UNION [ALL | DISTINCT] SELECT ...
[UNION [ALL | DISTINCT] SELECT ...]
```

Doc:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Edit:
I'll explain the query that you provided.

```
select count(*) from t1,t2 where t1.name=t2.name where t1.name='c';
```

First of all, you use `WHERE` clause twice which is a syntax error. Should be:

```
select count(*) from t1,t2 where t1.name=t2.name AND t1.name='c';
```

And this is the same that:

```
SELECT count(*) from t1
JOIN t2 ON t1.name=t2.name 
WHERE t1.name='c';
```

You choose only rows with `c` value so these are the rows, that we will take under consideration:

```
TABLE 1 (TABLE NAME T1)
SL   NAME
3     c
4     c 

table 2 (table name T2)
SL   NAME
2     c
3     c
4     c
```

Now, simple `JOIN`  joins every row from table 1 to every row from table 2 (where condition is true of course)

So the result before counting is:

```
t1.SL  t1.NAME  t2.SL  t2.NAME
3      c        2      c
4      c        3      c
3      c        4      c
4      c        2      c
3      c        3      c
4      c        4      c
```

This is 6 rows.

Answers for both of your questions.

```
SELECT name, count(*) as cnt
FROM(select t1.name from t1
     union all
     select name from t2) as tem
group by name
order by cnt DESC
```

This query will give you ranking of names ordered by occurrences.
To retrieve only `c` count, just add `WHERE` clause. To retrieve only the most occurring name set `LIMIT` clause to `1`.

Comment: You can give exact answer without giving link

Comment: I mean you have to provide solution without saying use union and all

Comment: There was no attempt to solve the problem by author so there shouldn't be the  exact answer.

Comment: So you can provide your idea in comment itself

Comment: select count(*) from t1,t2 where t1.name=t2.name where t1.name='c'; but it showing 6

Comment: hey give me answer...of Q1 and Q2 ?

Comment: Added answers for your questions.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO #test 
SELECT NAME FROM m_t1 WHERE NAME ='c'
UNION all
SELECT NAME FROM m_t2 WHERE NAME ='c'

SELECT count(*) FROM #test

Comment: use temperary table then only u can get your first question ans.(this is one of way)

Comment: Mani Kandan but its showing 2 and 5..but i want both combine in one answer means output 5